# How to use TextPrimary, TextSecondary color values in MudBlazor theme Palette

Tags: mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor and it provides a way to manage themes by defining the MudTheme.
e.g

```
MudTheme MyCustomTheme = new MudTheme()
{
  Palette = new Palette()
  {
     Primary = Colors.Blue.Default,
     Secondary = Colors.Blue.Default,
     AppbarBackground = "#FFFFFF",
     TextPrimary = "#000000",
     TextSecondary = "#FFFFFF",
  }
};
```

Setting `TextPrimary` color will set the provided value to scss variable `--mud-palette-text-primary` but not apply it to `MudText` component.

**Problem:** I am setting `TextPrimary` and `TextSecondary` in `Palette` but when I use the MudBlazor text component it doesn't apply the colors I provided.

```
<MudText Typo="Typo.h5">Application</MudText>
```

**Note:** MudText has a property Color which takes `Color enum` value but `Color enum` does't have a `TextPrimary` Value.

`Color` enum provided by MudBlazor

```
public enum Color
    {
        Default = 0,
        Primary = 1,
        Secondary = 2,
        Tertiary = 3,
        Info = 4,
        Success = 5,
        Warning = 6,
        Error = 7,
        Dark = 8,
        Transparent = 9,
        Inherit = 10,
        Surface = 11
    }
```

also if I set Color to primary like this

```
<MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Color="Color.Primary">Application</MudText>
```

it applies a css class .mud-primary-text or .mud-secondary-text based on parameter i passed, but inside these class they use `--mud-palette-primary` or `--mud-palette-secondary` scss variable instead of --mud-palette-primary-text`or`--mud-palette-secondary-text`

```
.mud-primary-text {
    color: var(--mud-palette-primary) !important; // it should use --mud-palette-primary-text 
}

.mud-secondary-text {
    color: var(--mud-palette-secondary) !important; // it should use --mud-palette-secondary-text 
}
```

At first, I thought by setting `Color` field to `Primary` `MudText component` will use `TextPrimary` value and other component will use `Primary` Value so I created a PR with a possible fix but they rejected it that it is like this by design. you can check it here https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/4451.

For now I have solved the problem by overriding the classes.

```
.mud-primary-text {
    color: var(--mud-palette-text-primary) !important;
}

.mud-secondary-text {
    color: var(--mud-palette-text-secondary) !important;
}
```

now is it a bug or my misunderstanding? looks like a bug to me.

**Note** After debugging I found out that if you use HTML headings or paragraph tags it'll apply colors define in Palette but if use MudText  component it'll not work because it applies `.mud-primary-text` class which set color to `--mud-palette-primary` so the way to solve this problem is to override the classes and set color to right scss variables, like i have showed above.

Answer (score 3):

For now, I have solved it by the below line of css

```
.mud-primary-text {
    color: var(--mud-palette-text-primary) !important;
}

.mud-secondary-text {
    color: var(--mud-palette-text-secondary) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works also for things like `mud-palette-surface`.